# What is the Microsoft name for WinDDK version 6001.18001?

Tags: visual-studio, wdk

I am trying to compile an old piece of code from 2009. In the compiler instructions the developer used Visual Studio 2008, .Net 2.0, and WinDDK:

Microsoft [Windows Driver Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/hardware/gg487428)

I need to know about WinDDK version 6001.18001 from the 2009 period.

What was the official Microsoft name for 6001.18001 version of WinDDK, and can you still download this from MSDN or TechNET?

(i.e.) WinDDK 7.1 is 7600.16385.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the WinDDK version 6001.18001 was named Windows Server 2008 WDK SP1.

WDK_6001_18001.iso, ca. 650MB

Release Date: WDK SP1 for Windows Server 2008 SP1 Release Date 10/23/2008

[It should be available with a Connect Account](https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=http://connect.microsoft.com&wctx=ru=https%253a%252f%252fconnect.microsoft.com%252fsite%252fsitehome.aspx%253fSiteID%253d148&wct=2012-09-26T12:17:43Z&wp=urn%3aliveid%3aMBI_FED_SSL_URI&wreply=https://connect.microsoft.com/dashboard/)

Comment: The WinDDK Windows Server 2008 SP1 is no longer available via connect.

Comment: Is there any other way to get this version of the DDK?  And are there any legal issues with downloading the DDK from websites that aren't affiliated with Microsoft?  I assume not because it was offered as a free product, but I'd just like to be sure.

Comment: @user1354557 - legal distribution from non affiliated Microsoft sites is questionable. I can't answer that, but there are torrents of this .iso file still available. When you install the DDK you still have to comply to license agreements set forth by Microsoft.